# How do users mount .bin/.cue or .iso with loopback device as read only?

Tags: mount, non-root-user, iso, loop-device

Can users mount any of the following image files as read-only using a 
loopback device?

If it is possible then can anyone give me examples?

Comment: no only root can.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of filesystem drivers: kernel or userland. Kernel filesystem drivers are the classical type. They are faster, but since they run kernel code, it is hard to control what they do. For this reason, by default only the system administrator (the root user) can mount a filesystem using a kernel filesystem driver.

The administrator can authorize other users to mount specific filesystems. There are several ways to do that, including:

- An entry in `/etc/fstab` with the options `user,noauto`, allowing any user to mount a specific filesystem at a specific location with specific options.
- The [`pmount`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmount) utility, which generally allows users to mount removable devices.

There is an [experimental version of pmount](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=373580) that supports loopback devices, but it isn't ready for prime time yet.

The other approach is to use a userland driver. This works through [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), which is a small kernel driver that only provides generic filesystem services; another program has to implement all the operations (opening files, listing directories, writing file data, etc.). Since everything the filesystem does is implemented by a user land process, a FUSE filesystem driver can only do what the user was allowed to do anyway by running this process. Therefore there is no security issue in allowing all users to mount whatever filesystem they want. The FUSE driver only makes some basic sanity checks such as requiring that the user doing the mounting owns the mount point, and forbidding the user from advertising files as belonging to other users.

[View OS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/view-os/) contains a FUSE driver for CD (ISO 9660) images, which is packaged in Debian as [`fuseiso9660`](http://pacakges.debian.org/fuseiso9660).
[FuseIso](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/wiki.old/index.php/FuseIso) is another one that looks unmaintained.

Another way to mount CD images is to leverage the capability of the [Gnome virtual filesystem (GVFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS). Thanks to `gvfs-fuse`, anything that Gnome applications can believe to be a filesystem can be a genuine filesystem. See [Can I mount an ISO without administrative privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4140/can-i-mount-an-iso-without-administrative-privileges) for more details.

bin/cue files are a bit more complex. [How do I mount .cue file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4158/how-do-i-mount-cue-file) offers several solutions:

- [Use](https://askubuntu.com/a/4170) [iat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/iat.1.html) to make a `.iso`
- [Use](https://askubuntu.com/a/140256) [bchunk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bchunk.1.html) to make a `.iso`
- [Use](https://askubuntu.com/a/4160) fuseiso

Answer (score -1):

In order to mount a ISO/BIN/CUE file as a loopback device (i.e. mount -o loop) the user must be a member of the group with which is assigned to the file.

Additional methods of mounting the file are to set the SUID bit, assign the user to the cdrom group, setting the user/group combination as options within the /etc/fstab file etc.

See 'man mount' for more information about the possibilities.